# Interpolating a JavaScript expression into an object which is a React prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code which doesn't work

```
tabs.map(tabs, (tab) => (
    <Tab options={{'option':{tab.key === 'value'}}}>
        ...
    </Tab>
));
```

My problem is `some.key`, which is throwing an error because I'm obviously not interpolating this expression properly.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do please? I can't do it in a separate expression because the `options` is dependant on the `tab` being mapped over.

Comment: `'option':{tab.key === 'value'}` isn't valid, which probably causes your issue. Did you want it to evaluate to `'option': true` (or false, depending on the value)? If so, you want `'option': tab.key === 'value'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid syntax for an object literal. Also, assuming that `tabs` is an iterable, the first parameter of `map()` should be the mapping function.

The following should work:

```
tabs.map(tab => (
    <Tab options={{option: tab.key === 'value'}}>
        ...
    </Tab>
));
```

To make it cleaner, define your `options` before rendering the component:

```
tabs.map(tab => {
    const options = {option: tab.key === 'value'};

    return (
        <Tab options={options}>
            ...
        </Tab>
    );
});
```